# ChartJS: Time series not rendering at all

Tags: charts, momentjs

Chart JS 3.0.0
Charts JS not showing time series at all.
To support time, we need to have moment js but in Chart 3.0 even after adding moment js it is not working
Here is source code:

```
    let ctx = document.querySelector("#progresschart").getContext('2d');
progresschart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: { datasets: datasetss },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

And this is how chart js rendering:
[image: Chart js view]

This issues is with chart js 3.0 only.
If chart js version 2.0 used all good.

Comment: Can you import a working snippet of code? Maybe with a dataset too?